# unable to install jaspersoft studio in eclipse due to dependencies

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jaspersoft-studio

while trying to install jasper studio in eclipse from eclipse marketplace, I got an error saying the jasper studio can't be installed due to some unmet dependencies. It said that the studio required  `eclipse.pde.ui.git` bundle which it could not find. Please help me find the solution for this. What should I do? I searched over the the net but could not find a solution.